electron-forge require function outside of exe
im making a electron based app and want to require every file from custom/scripts folder
in forge.config.js i have already made the folder to not be included in the exe
...
packagerConfig: {
   asar: {
   unpackDir: "custom",
   },
...

Now it won't dynamicly load the scripts in the custom/scripts directory even if i change the code to load from path.join(__dirname, "./app-0.1.0/resources/app.asar.unpacked/custom/scripts")
I would really appriciate help
Update
Solved the issue by using ChatGPT and after 3h of prompting has led me to this:
path.join(process.resourcesPath, "app.asar.unpacked", "custom", "scripts")

Don't get me wrong it works, but 3h?...
